# How can I use CSS to put an image next to each menu item?

Tags: css, drupal, menu, background, background-image

I'm using Drupal 7.26 - I've created a menu and entered some links into the menu. I'm trying to style the menu now - it has output the links as a bulleted list.

I've styled the li element to give padding, margin, text colour and a background colour. I now have each menu item inside a blue box which is what I was looking for. However, I now need to take away the bullet points which are to the left and outside of the blue background of each menu item, and instead, inside the menu item background box, I need a background image placed to the left of the text.

My question is, how can I place the little image to the left of the text?

Thank you v much.

Comment: u can insert images instead of built points. i'm sure. but if u need biger pics u simply put image tag before link and with ccs left align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

```
li{
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-image: url('image/path/here');
}
```

if not, please post a fiddle.

The above code will style all `li`'s in your page. to make it specific, use class names. 

 like `ul.menu li`..

Comment: GREAT! Thank you very much that's exactly what I was looking for. Just for anyone else in future looking at this, I also had to add line-height and padding to ul li a and li as the text was appearing to the right but at the bottom of the image, so I needed to add padding and line height to make it look like the text at the right of the image was vertically aligned center

Comment: @CarlBowles very good.. if my answer is helpful to you please mark it as answer. :)

Comment: @CarlBowles please mark his answer as good (click on little "V" on the left of the answer to turn it green). It would be nice for him ;o)